# How to add scroll in bundled product custom options?

Tags: magento2.2, bundled-product

I have created one bundled product and I have added 9 sub-products in this product

Refer below screenshot for all sub-products:

[image]

I want to add a scrollbar when the no. of sub-products are greater than 7. So how can I achieve this?

Below file is for bundle product:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor_name/mytheme/Magento_Bundle/templates/catalog/product 
>    /view/type/bundle/options.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /** @var $block Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle */ ?>
<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
$helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<?php $options = $block->decorateArray($block->getOptions()); ?>
<?php if ($product->isSaleable()):?>
    <?php if (count($options)): ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "priceBundle": {
                "optionConfig": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig()?>,
                "controlContainer": ".field.option"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
        <fieldset class="fieldset fieldset-bundle-options">        
            <div class="title"><?php echo __('Test Products'); ?></div>        

            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('product_info_bundle_options_top');?>
            <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
                <?php if (!$option->getSelections()): ?>
                    <?php continue; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $block->getOptionHtml($option) ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </fieldset>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="empty"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('No options of this product are available.') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

**NOTE**: I want to add scroll programmatically  without using any CSS style